# Process multiple files at once using awk and parallel

Tags: shell, csv, awk, gnu-parallel

I have more than a hundred part .csv files that contain data delimited by '|'. I need to add prefix on second column of each part file using awk and parallel.

I am doing single file at a time, but is taking hours. so wanted to go with parallel.

## input1.csv

10|20

10|30

10|40

## input2.csv

20|30

20|40

line1|10

## output expected

## input1.csv

10|P20

10|P30

10|P40

## input2.csv

20|P30

20|P40

line1|P10

I am using this, and working when I do one file at a time, but I need something faster that will do multiple files using parallel

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$2 = "P" $2} 1' input1.csv > in.tmp && mv in.tmp input1.csv

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$2 = "P" $2} 1' input2.csv > in.tmp && mv in.tmp input2.csv

end finally merge all the input*.csv files into input

Comment: `finally merge all the input*.csv files into input` How do you merge them>?

Comment: @KamilCuk something like this cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > 0.txt, but I have thousand files, something easier would be good

Comment: `output expected` so do you care about each every individual file being modified, or do you only care about the end `0.txt` file? Are you _sure_ your process is not limited by I/O? There's like no point in running parallel computation, if you have one disc - your I/O will be limited by your one disc anyway.

Comment: If you are working on 1, or maybe 10 files, it is not too horrible to edit the files in place.  If you are working on a large number of files, you are just asking for trouble if you edit the files in place.

Comment: Recreate the output files in a new directory tree, or you will wind up ending the process half way through with some fraction of the files modified and some unmodified, and then you'll have to add logic to avoid making things worse.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am running on aws, so multiple cpu's and multiple processors

Comment: @WilliamPursell I will do 20 or 30 files at a time, but the number of files are in hundreds. I have space limitations as some of these file are pretty big

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for hot to format your sample input, output, and code.

Comment: Superficially, I think `sed 's/|/|P/' input*.csv > input` would do the trick unless you have limitations on the length of your command line (so the `input*.csv` list is too big).  If you do have such problems, then consider `find . -name 'input*.csv' -exec sed 's/|/|P/' {} + > input`.  I'm interpreting "merge all the `input*.csv` files into `input`" as requesting that the output is a file called `input`.  This does not modify the `input*.csv` files; if that's a crucial part of the operation, you need a different answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this does the trick for me

```
parallel "awk -F'|' '{print \$1\"|\"\"PO\"\$2}' {} > {}.tmp; mv {}.tmp {}" ::: input*.csv
```

Comment: You can do the merge in one step: `parallel "awk -F'|' '{print \$1\"|\"\"PO\"\$2}' {}" ::: input*.csv > merged.csv`